# Generate Script in SQL Server 2000 (in Order)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I want Generate script of all views and functions in my database, but when i execute this script i find a problem of ("object xxx doesn't exist") because i have many views select data from other views, so they should be created before the first ones.

So i want a way to generate the script in order or other solution

I use SQL Server 2000.

Comment: Can I ask what you intend to use the script for?

Answer (score 0):

No idea about how to do it resources available in SQL Server 2000 itself. But I think you can use this tool to accomplish what you're expecting.

[Red Gate SQL Multi Script](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-multi-script/)